# How would I reverse this? C#

Tags: c#

hi there i need to reverse this codes

```
    public static byte[] CreateProtocolBuffer(params int[] values)
    {
        List<byte> ptr = new List<byte>();
        for (int x = 0; x < values.Length; x++)
        {
            int value = values[x];
            while (value > 0x7F)
            {
                ptr.Add((byte)((value & 0x7F) | 0x80));
                value >>= 7;
            }
            ptr.Add((byte)(value & 0x7F));

        }
        return ptr.ToArray();
    }
```

ex:

```
int ID = 1000005;
byte[] ptr = CreateProtocolBuffer(ID);
```

I need to use the values in `ptr` to get 1000005 back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add more details to clarify the question you are asking and provide necessary context.  Right now it's difficult to understand what the goal is here.

Comment: *always* adds it back, even if it wasn't there. This isn't reversible.

Comment: @Blindy Huh?  This is a simple variable-length encoding using 7 bits of data per output byte.  Why wouldn't it be reversible?

Comment: it should revers the encoding data comes from client i must decoding to get the values back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the `CreateProtocolBuffer` method you posted encodes each integer value as a stream of bytes where each byte contains 7 bits of data and a 'continue' flag (in the high bit).  Depending on the value being encoded it can produce between 1 and 5 bytes of output.

To reverse the encoding you need to read bytes until you find one that the high bit cleared, taking the 7 bits from each byte to composite together to get the original value.

Here's a simple reversal of your code:

```
public static int[] FromProtocolBuffer(byte[] buffer)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    short shift = 0;
    int curr = 0;
    foreach (byte b in buffer)
    {
        curr = curr | (((int)b & 0x7F) << shift);
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0)
        {
            result.Add(curr);
            curr = 0;
            shift = 0;
        }
        else
            shift += 7;
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Just be careful that you don't try to encode negative values this way or it won't work.  Better to make the whole thing work on unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this out and take into account that suggested encoding schema doesn't work with negative numbers (information about sign stored in the leading bits is lost).

```
public static int[] BackConversion(byte[] b)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    int current = 0;
    int i_start = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        current += (b[i] & 0x7F) << (i - i_start) * 7;

        if ((b[i] & 0x80) == 0)
        {
            result.Add(current);
            i_start = i + 1;
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Here is how to make the whole thing (encoding/decoding) work with negative numbers. Replace `int value = values[x];` by `uint value = (uint)values[x];` in your encoding code.

Comment: `CreateProtocolBuffer` takes int array. so `BackConversion` must return int array too. this works for only one number.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, I thought the rest could be exercise for the question's author. I've updated the answer.